# Refining an BigQuery table with external API lookup

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have a table in Google BigQuery.
The table contains adresses(danish) - eg. Streetname: "Bakkevej", Housenumber: "23" and Zip: "4305".

As I need to match the data with another table containing universal(danish) adress IDs - Called DAWAID - I need to lookup the adress agains an API and add the DAWAID for the adress to a seperate field in the row called DAWAID.

The API is placed on: https://dawa.aws.dk/adresser and is returning data as JSON - but it is possible to get returned as jsonp or ndjson.

The lookup for the adress mentioned would look like this: https://dawa.aws.dk/adresser?vejnavn=Bakkevej&husnr=23&postnr=4305

So - the question is this. How would I go around getting all rows in the table looked up against the API and save the returned DAWAID ("id" in the JSON).

I have thought that it could might be done with a combination of the bq commandline and curl - but this is kind of a long shot.

Any way to do this in the Google Cloud?

Comment: How many rows you have? Do you know if the API is rate limited?

Comment: There is around 500.000 rows - the API is limited to 10 concurrent requests at a time - but as far as I know there is not other limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery does not include a way to make external lookups of data.

Instead, I suggest using a batch processing system that can iterate through the whole database, do the lookup for each row, and then save it back to a new table.

GCP includes a system capable of this, [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/). In Dataflow you will basically need a three compmonent pipeline:

1. a BigQuery Source to get the rows from your current table
2. A Transform you will have to write to fetch the DAWAID and include that in each row
3. A BigQuery Sink to write the rows with the DAWID to a new table.